# csv string to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have csv text as like below

```
Keyword;Search Volume;CPC;Competition;Number of Results;Trends
shoes of ladies;90;0.00;0.00;96700000;0.11,0.11,0.11,0.22,0.11,0.11,1.00,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11
ladys shoes;110;0.95;1.00;96800000;0.79,0.64,0.50,0.79,1.00,0.79,0.79,0.79,0.64,0.50,0.64,1.00
kadies shoes;90;1.16;1.00;116000000;0.44,1.00,1.00,0.11,1.00,0.78,0.56,0.11,0.56,0.33,0.33,1.00
shoes ladies;390;1.20;1.00;119000000;0.54,0.54,0.54,0.81,1.00,1.00,0.81,0.67,1.00,0.67,0.67,0.81
shoes for ladies;140;1.38;1.00;132000000;0.42,0.27,0.35,0.42,0.54,0.65,0.42,0.27,0.42,0.81,0.65,1.00
laddies shoes;90;2.23;1.00;76800000;0.22,0.33,0.11,0.44,0.11,0.78,0.33,0.22,0.78,0.11,0.11,1.00
ladies shoe;90;1.50;1.00;52400000;0.45,0.64,0.82,0.82,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.82,0.64,0.82,0.82
ladies shoes uk;2900;1.19;1.00;34700000;0.43,0.66,0.82,0.82,0.82,1.00,0.66,0.66,0.55,0.55,0.66,0.66
ladies black shoes;590;1.31;1.00;63600000;0.67,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.82,1.00
black ladies shoes;320;1.34;1.00;131000000;0.67,0.67,0.67,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.82,1.00,1.00
```

and in this ; deliminator seperates my data . and the very first line was my header  `Keyword;Search Volume;CPC;Competition;Number of Results;Trends` so total 6 headers .

i am trying to get the array like as below

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Keyword"]=>"shoes of ladies"
    ["Search Volume"]=>"90"
    ["CPC"]=> "0.00"
    ["Competition"]=> "0.11"
    ["Number of Results"]=> "96700000"
    ["Trends"]=>
        array(){
        [0]=>0.11,
        [1]=>0.11,
        [2]=>0.11
        ...
        []
        }

  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Keyword"]=>"ladys shoes"
    ["Search Volume"]=>"90"
    ["CPC"]=> "0.00"
    ["Competition"]=> "0.11"
    ["Number of Results"]=> "96700000"
    ["Trends"]=>
        array(){
        [0]=>0.11,
        [1]=>0.11,
        [2]=>0.11
        ...
        []
        }
  }
```

i was trying with code

```
$url = "Keyword;Search Volume;CPC;Competition;Number of Results;Trends
shoes of ladies;90;0.00;0.00;96700000;0.11,0.11,0.11,0.22,0.11,0.11,1.00,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11
ladys shoes;110;0.95;1.00;96800000;0.79,0.64,0.50,0.79,1.00,0.79,0.79,0.79,0.64,0.50,0.64,1.00
kadies shoes;90;1.16;1.00;116000000;0.44,1.00,1.00,0.11,1.00,0.78,0.56,0.11,0.56,0.33,0.33,1.00
shoes ladies;390;1.20;1.00;119000000;0.54,0.54,0.54,0.81,1.00,1.00,0.81,0.67,1.00,0.67,0.67,0.81
shoes for ladies;140;1.38;1.00;132000000;0.42,0.27,0.35,0.42,0.54,0.65,0.42,0.27,0.42,0.81,0.65,1.00
laddies shoes;90;2.23;1.00;76800000;0.22,0.33,0.11,0.44,0.11,0.78,0.33,0.22,0.78,0.11,0.11,1.00
ladies shoe;90;1.50;1.00;52400000;0.45,0.64,0.82,0.82,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.82,0.64,0.82,0.82
ladies shoes uk;2900;1.19;1.00;34700000;0.43,0.66,0.82,0.82,0.82,1.00,0.66,0.66,0.55,0.55,0.66,0.66
ladies black shoes;590;1.31;1.00;63600000;0.67,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.82,0.82,1.00
black ladies shoes;320;1.34;1.00;131000000;0.67,0.67,0.67,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.67,0.67,0.82,0.82,1.00,1.00" ;


$lines = explode("\n", $url);

$head = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines));

$data = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$data[] = array_combine($head, str_getcsv($line));
}
```

so its not giving me the desired output. any suggestions please

Comment: Can't you download the data file other format ? Like JSON or so ?

Comment: actually its coming from external api URL . @pinoyCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $lines = explode("\n", $url);

    $head = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines),";");

    $data = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $tempArr = str_getcsv($line,";");
        $tempArr[5] = explode(",",$tempArr[5]);
        $data[] = array_combine($head, $tempArr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$head = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines), ";");
$data = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $tmp = array_combine($head, str_getcsv($line, ";"));
   $tmp['Trends'] = explode(",", $tmp['Trends'])
   $data[] = $tmp;
}
```

This is the explanation:
As described here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php, you forgot to set the correct delemiter. Which is by default ',' and you need ';'.

Comment: But the array is not coming my desire way. any suggestions ?

Comment: I have changed my answer it a little bit.